# How to ensure the accuracy of aggregated data in PostgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have two PostgreSQL tables - table A contains individual client's credit movements records (increase / decrease) and Table B contains data of aggregated table A. Simplified structure of the tables (I removed FK and rules):

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."credit_review" (
      "id" SERIAL, 
      "client_id" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
      "credit_change" INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
      "itime" TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
) WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE TABLE "public"."credit_review_aggregated" (
  "id" SERIAL, 
  "credit_amount" INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
  "valid_to_review_id" INT NOT NULL, 
  "client_id" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  "itime" TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

Column "credit_review_aggregated.valid_to_review_id" is FK to "credit_review.id".

Because it is very important to have data in aggregation table correct I'm looking for a way of ensuring this need. It occurred to me:

1. Disable deleting and udpating records in both tables
2. On aggregated table create trigger to check if the entered data are correct (and if not, don't allow insert). I don't like it too much because when a record is inserted into aggregation tables credit_amount value will be counted twice (once in application a second time in the trigger).

Do you have some advice for me how to ensure this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on the invariant you're trying to enforce, but from the general outlines of the problem, I would be inclined to use trigger code to enforce it, and ues SERIALIZABLE transactions.  Enforcing invariants across multiple tables becomes very tricky very quickly otherwise.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI

Full disclosure: Because my employer needed to enforce complex integrity rules across multiple tables, I worked on adding SSI to PostgreSQL, along with Dan R.K. Ports of MIT.